# Deploy LibreOffice with Ansible

Tags: deployment, ansible

So, I'm just getting started with ansible. Currently, I try to install/update the latest version of LibreOffice to linux machines in the network. I've run into a weird issue I don't know how to approach. The playbook is pretty simple and probably not fool-proof, but at the moment I'm just trying to make it work somehow.

```
---
- name: "Update LibreOffice on Linux"

  hosts: linux

  tasks:
          - name: "Copy LibreOffice debs to local machines"
            copy:
                    src: /root/deploy
                    dest: /tmp



          - name: "Locating main office debs"
            find:
                    paths: /tmp/deploy/libreoffice6.3/office/DEBS
                    patterns: '*.deb'
            register: office_debs

            #- debug:
            #      var: office_debs


          - name: "Deleting previous LibreOffice instances"
            apt:
                    name: ['libreoffice*']
                    state: absent
                    purge: yes


          - name: "Installing main office debs"
            apt:
                   deb: "{{ item.path }}"
                   state: present
            with_items:
                   "{{ office_debs.files }}"
```

The "linux" host group currenlty includes only one machine that runs mint 19.1. The files get copied, previous version of LibreOffice, if there are any, get deleted, but on the installation phase I get a bunch of error messages like this:

```
failed: [10.50.9.80] (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1576748471.011039, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/deploy/libreoffice6.3/office/DEBS/libobasis6.3-calc_6.3.4.2-2_amd64.deb', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1576751357.10336, u'inode': 524508, u'isgid': False, u'size': 7109958, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1576748471.2710397, u'isblk': False, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 2049, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"atime": 1576751357.10336, "ctime": 1576748471.2710397, "dev": 2049, "gid": 0, "gr_name": "root", "inode": 524508, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "mode": "0644", "mtime": 1576748471.011039, "nlink": 1, "path": "/tmp/deploy/libreoffice6.3/office/DEBS/libobasis6.3-calc_6.3.4.2-2_amd64.deb", "pw_name": "root", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 7109958, "uid": 0, "wgrp": false, "woth": false, "wusr": true, "xgrp": false, "xoth": false, "xusr": false}, "msg": "Неразрешимая зависимость: libobasis6.3-core (>= 6.3.4.2)\n"}
```

The Russian bit at the end says "unresolved dependency".
The libobasic6.3-core package is right the in the same folder. If I log on to this mint machine and run "dpkg -i *.deb", the office gets installed just fine.

I'm probably missing something very basic here but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

UPD Actually, if I run this once, SOME of the packages (like libobasis6.3-core) do get installed. If I comment out the "delete" section in the playbook and run it for the second time, it installs the rest of the packages. I guess this is better than nothing, but still it's not a solution.

Comment: Hi. I see some (secondary) things to improve in your playbook, but my main question would be, why not just use the apt module to install from repository instead of a .deb file?

Comment: I tried using the apt module before, but it doesn't do too good either. On this particular machine, it installs libreoffice 6.3 as I want it to, but on the other one it installs version 6.0.7 for some reason (beside the machine having a later version of mint). I tried adding the libreoffice ppa on all machines, but it fails the cache update (on some of them it doesn't tho). Anyway, this is another nut to crack. The way I see it, installing from the debs should be more reliable in this case, because I'd be sure it's the same version everywhere.

Comment: Since you mention that apt is failing on several machines, but not one in particular: Are you using the same Linux distribution and version on all machines?

Comment: Your problem is not with ansible neither with programming. This is a pure apt config issue ([off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO). Once it is ruled out, you just have to basically `apt: name=openoffice-<version> state=present`. Try https://superuser.com

Comment: The issue is that the `with_items` loop is installing one item at a time, this is different from the `*.deb` wildcard approach that works for you. You might want to install the `libobasis6.3-core` package first using the `apt` module, then the other packages. Or define the list of `deb` packages in order of priority. The `with_items` loop is going to run one install command per package, which means that you will have to have the right order for things to work.

Comment: Zeitounator, for openoffice maybe, but I need libreoffice specifically and it doesn't seem to be so easy with it. Anyway, I figure my problem was that the PPAs I was trying to add were for Ubuntu and Mint doesn't like him those Ubuntu repos. On Ubuntu machines installation through apt works fine, for Mint I've devised a workaround with "shell: dpkg -i *.deb". I'll leave it at that for now, at least until I figure out how to get that Ubuntu repo work on Mint.